# Using lodash to sort an array of objects on a floating point number

Tags: javascript, sorting, lodash

I have a Javascript array like this:

```
var list = [{Name: 'X', Value: 140.000},
{Name: 'Y', Value: 200.000},
{Name: 'Z', Value: 50.000}]
```

(it has many more properties, but has been omitted for brevity).

I've created a function that sorts this list using the name of the property passed into the function. I've done this easily with lodash, but if I sort on Value, the values seem to be treated a strings and get sorted wrong.

This is my sort function (so far)

```
function sortByField(fieldName)
    {
        list = _.sortBy(list, fieldName);

        //afterwards I call reverse() if the sortDirection is descending, but I omitted this part for brevity
    }
```

After sorting on Value I get the following array:

```
var list = [{Name: 'X', Value: 140.000},
{Name: 'Y', Value: 200.000},
{Name: 'Z', Value: 50.000}]
```

You can see it treated the Values like strings, even though they are decimal numbers. The 'Z'-object should have been first. How can I solve this?

I've been searching through the lodash documentation but couldn't seem to find anything related to this problem. Any help please? It'll be much appreciated.

EDIT: I just realized that the Value-property is filled in through a web page (an input control) so Javascript actually adds it to the array as a String, which probably causes the problem. Can I somehow cast this to a float? Or do I have to resort to the built in sort function of Javascript and create my own Compare?

Comment: Just use the plain built-in JavaScript `.sort()` with a callback to return the difference between the two "Value" properties.

Comment: why the positions after the decimal point?

Comment: Oh, that's a thousands-seperator, not a decimal point in the example. In my country the "." is a thousands seperator :-)

Comment: but then it's wrong you need a number, or a string and sort by a custom string value.

Answer (score 2):

What you posted:

```
var list = [{Name: 'X', Value: 140.000},
   {Name: 'Y', Value: 200.000},
   {Name: 'Z', Value: 50.000}];

list = _.sortBy(list, 'Value');
console.log(list);
```

should work as expected.

http://jsbin.com/fegifibasu/edit?js,console

Now if for some reason (as you mentioned), the Value field contains string instead of float, then you would need to write your 'custom' sort function.  For example:

```
var list = [{Name: 'X', Value: '140.000'},
  {Name: 'Y', Value: '200.000'},
  {Name: 'Z', Value: '50.000'}];

list = _.sortBy(list, function(o) {
  return parseFloat(o.Value);
});
console.log(list);
```

http://jsbin.com/gagelipuza/edit?js,console

Comment: and how to order by asc desc? it's not working when u need to order...

Comment: After _sortBy add the following for DESC.

list = _.reverse(list)

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`Array#sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) with a custom `compareFunction` and replace unwanted characters like `'.'` with `''` and a possible decimal separator `','` with dot.

```js
var list = [{ Name: 'X', Value: '140.000' }, { Name: 'Y', Value: '200.000' }, { Name: 'Z', Value: '50.000' }];

list.sort(function (a, b) {
    function getValue(v) {
        return parseFloat(v.replace('.', '').replace(',', '.'));
    }
    return getValue(a.Value) - getValue(b.Value);
});

console.log(list);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```